# Why are some of the statements in Apache IoTDB Version 1.3 can only be executed with `;` mark?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I execute statements in Cli tool of Apache IoTDB, why do some statements can be executed before adding `;` and some can be executed without adding `;`? I just downloaded Version 1.3 of Apache IoTDB, and it seems that this problem has not occurred in before versions. For example, if I directly use `show timeseries` command, the results can be returned. If I don't add `;` to `show databases` or `delete database` command, it will keep waiting for input. Anyone know why may be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in github of Apache IoTDB. We will fix it in Version 1.3.1, or you can continue to use the Cli tool of Version 1.2 to connect to the IoTDB database of Version 1.3.0.